# How I can change the position of subfolders in Outlook through c# program

Tags: outlook-addin

How I can change the position of subfolders in Outlook through c# program. lest say I have 3 subfolders in my Inbox , a,b, c .. I want arrange the structure of subfolders like ,

Inbox-> 
   b,
   a,
   c.

Please share me the script of code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Non-default folders are always shown sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use NavigationFolder.Position to rearrange the folder?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you have questions regarding the subject or want something clarified, use the comment function. Create an answer if you know of a solution that works.